# Pull filenames using .bat - windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have implemented the line:

```
C:\Customers> for /f "@delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d *.*') do @echo %%~nxa >> outputfile.txt
```

Directly into command prompt and it outputs the filenames in all the sub directories like so into a .txt file:

> Crook.png
>
> Hatchet.png
>
> test.csv

But when I go to implement this in a .bat file it creates the .txt file but it remains blank.

Anyone know how to implement this as a batch so it will output the .txt filled with the text.

Thanks

Comment: Hi again - batch files require % to be doubled in the batch file `%%a` and `%%~nxa`.

Comment: @Ben [Here is the reference](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: Hi Andy I have tried that still doesn't output correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@` symbol. If you are trying to hide the line from the terminal then do it at the start of the command:

`@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d *.*') do @echo %%~nxa >> outputfile.txt`